# SVG comparison (regression testing)

Tags: c#, svg, regression-testing

I am searching for the most optimal way to compare svg files that come as an output of SpecFlow tests of the C# project I am working on. The goal is that after implemented functionality I can compare all files created before and after and pinpoint the parts of svg that were changed, or make sure that files remained the same. Note that there are some hidden objects rendered, so pixel-by-pixel comparison of the files would not work.

Is there any existing tool where I can upload two files (before and after changes and have both of the images displayed, but also see the changes in the xml structure?

Is there any existing library for C# that does this, so I can implement automatic regression tests (in case I would like that output remains the same)?

Comment: Why would hidden objects be rendered? Switch to a less buggy viewer implementation perhaps?

Comment: Can you show an example of [svg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics)-files? If structure is heavily altered (adding invisible element, layers, etc.), then pixel-to-pixel comparison of **rendered result** is the way to go, otherwise a simple line-to-line ([diff](https://www.diffchecker.com/9SLloJ7E)) comparison should do.

Comment: SVGs are indeed heavily altered and contain more than 1000 lines of code. They contain a lot of nested groups holding transformations and are created using recursive algorithm.
PIxel-by-pixel might indeed be easier solution for regression, but won't be able to pinpoint where exactly changes occur.
On the other hand if I want to compare on xml level I have to delete comments and many unimportant properties. So the question would be how could I do that easily?
Is there any tool that can compare nested transformations and identify them es equal to a flattened one?